# error C2084: function 'int main(void)' already has a body

Tags: c++

Can someone help me to sort out this ERROR

I have Two files under source files in visual studio 2013 express
main.cpp and Variables.cpp

below are the codes

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwmgX.png)
[WARNING AND ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gid5R.png)

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Variables.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a = 3;

cout << "Hello World" << endl;
cout << "The value of a: " << a << endl;
getchar();

return 0;

}
```

**Variables.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Declaring Variables
int a = 3;
float b = 33.3;
double c = 223.334;
char d = 'i';
string e = "This is a test text !";

//Printing
cout << "The value of a: " << a << endl;
cout << "The value of b: " << b << endl;
cout << "The value of c: " << c << endl;
cout << "The value of d: " << d << endl;
cout << "The value of e: " << e << endl;

//Show Msg
getchar();
return 0;

}
```

**Error**

Warning 1
warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'float' c:\users\iifra\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\testproject001\testproject001\variables.cpp    11  1   TestProject001

Error   2
error C2084: function 'int main(void)' already has a body   c:\users\iifra\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\testproject001\testproject001\main.cpp 6   1   TestProject001

Warning 3
warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'float' c:\users\iifra\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\testproject001\testproject001\variables.cpp    11  1   TestProject001

Comment: You can't link two compilation units with duplicate definitions of the same function.

Comment: I didn't understand, which , do you mean #include "Variables.cpp"

Comment: you can not have 2 'int main(void)' methods in the same project!

Comment: Don't include a .cpp!

Comment: 1) Why do you include `.cpp` files? They aren't meant to be included. 2) You can only have _one_ `main` per executable, yet now you have two.

Comment: Change `float b = 33.3;` to`float b = 33.3f;`

Comment: Please help me, how should the code look like. I am beginner,

Comment: Start to read a C++ book.

Comment: main() is the starting point of your program! You cannot have two starting points

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of function `main()` present in Variables.cpp to any other name.
You can not use two main() functions under same project because your OS finds the main function present in your project when you run your project. And here OS is confused which main function to call first.

Comment: "Change the name of function main() present in Variables.cpp to any other name." So... changing the name to `getchar` would work?

Comment: Yes it would work but it would be recursion and your program has no any exit statement, so it will run for infinite time.

Answer (score 0):

It's a beginners question. Two aspects:

- you can only have 1 'main' function, since 'main' is special (entry point)
- you can use multiple source files; use header for declarations and source for definitions

e.g.:

main source:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "variables.hpp"

int main()
{
   int a = 3;

   std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "The value of a: " << a << std::endl;

   //invoke f 
   f();

   //getchar();

   return 0;    
}
```

variables header:

```
//variables.hpp

void f();
```

variables source:

```
//variables.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "variables.hpp"

void f()
{
   std::cout << "Bla" << std::endl;
}
```

The compiler will treat them as two translation units and creates two obj files (i.e. main.obj and variables.obj) and the linker will merge them together as one exe.

You are using Visual Studio. Put the header files under the header folder and cpp files under the source folder.